# Cannot connect in multiplayer since version 11.1

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Me and my friend have been able to play Minecraft together in the past, but now with version 11.1 we can't play together although we are connected to the same WiFi and we have our multiplayer settings on. Her name never pops on my screen and same for her with me. We enjoy playing together and now we can't! Can someone help us please?!

Comment: Are you playing over LAN or using a standalone server?

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if this helps at all, since I have not seen this kind of issue since version 11.0. 
It can take a while before you can see each other through WiFi.

We have found that it helps if the person(s) on the server stands still and looks up into the sky, reducing the server workload to a minimum.

Answer (score -1):

Try looking in the multiplayer area were you can turn it off and on. Keep trying until you see something hopefully.